# App Engine Pull queue only load a subset of tasks

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, task-queue, pull-queue

Can I set a minimum time before a task is fetched from the task queue? I want to process a task after X days e.g.
Is there a simple way or should I put this information it the task itself? It sounds  inefficient to load all the tasks every 2 hours (e.g. with a cron job) if most of then should only be executed in 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`etaMillis`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#etaMillis%28long%29) or [`countdownMillis`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#countdownMillis%28long%29) in [`TaskOptions`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#countdownMillis%28long%29).

No worker should be allowed to lease the tasks before the specific time is elapsed as shown in the [Task Queue Python documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/functions):

> Argument: countdown
>
> Functionality in Pull Queues: Designates how long to wait, in seconds, before allowing the task to be leased.
>
> Argument: eta
>
> Functionality in Pull Queues: Designates the earliest time that a worker can lease a task. No worker can lease a task